# What are the ways to load a database?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm looking at the docs here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/gettingstarted.html#database-connection

If I have my database in my config like:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test123"
db.default.user=root
db.default.pass=""
```

How do I load my database?

```
Do I use Database.forURL( ???)  // I already have this in my config
```

I'm confused how do I load a database using the application.conf settings.  All the examples I see are using hard coded values using .forUrl.

Also, I see some examples using the following package/namespace, but I can't seem to get this to resolve:

```
import play.api.db._
```

So I can't create a datasource because `DB` doesn't seem to be in the same namespace now.

Comment: `play-jdbc` has `DB.getDataSource`, slick has `Database.forDaraSource`. There is also a module https://github.com/freekh/play-slick

Answer (score 1):

The Slick documentation describes the Slick library independent of Play. In Play, Slick is configured through the config files. You then simply need to use DBAction and everything works.

```
import play.api.db.slick._
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._

object Application extends Controller{
  //create an instance of the table
  val Cats = TableQuery[CatsTable] //see a way to architect your app in the computers-database-slick sample

  def index = DBAction { implicit rs =>
    Ok(views.html.index(Cats.list))
  }
  ...
```

Also see: https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/blob/master/samples/play-slick-sample/app/controllers/Application.scala

Comment: But I want to have my queries inside of a service layer or DAO.  And the option to configure multiple databases in my conf file.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is that I want to use slick with play, but have my service/model layer outside of play so I can re-use it other applications.

Comment: Multiple databases is a separate issue. I don't know how exactly that is handled. I think you can configure multiple data sources and access them by name somehow. Separating the model layer comes down to configuration as well I suppose. If you use the play config for the db, you will not be independent of play. You could totally abandon the play config for the db and simple use Slick as described in the Slick documentation.

Comment: So is there a single place I can put `val Cats = TableQuery[CatsTable]` or I have to put these all over my controllers whenever I need to query from these tables?

Comment: ok. so for `import play.api.db.slick._` you need the play-slick plugin. Or you ignore the plugin, but Slick doesn't know how to read your play config. Take your pick :).

Comment: just want to confirm, Datasource is of type java.sql.datasource and the type returned for Database.forDataSource is DatabaseDef or is it scala.slick.session.Database?  intellij seems to link to to DatabaseDef for some wierd reason.